# What is the difference between cache property of Fetch and axios api

Tags: reactjs, axios, fetch

while working on an browser issue ,I found out the axios api was caching the response and fetch api did not ,even though I have not use any cache specific property in headers  for both the apis.
Can somebody please help understand this.

Comment: You can add `'Cache-Control': 'no-store'` in axios request headers if you want to disable caching of requests.